# Javascript Canvas Game Delta Time

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm working on a simple javascript canvas based game, everything is going well except for the attempting to get the delta time to calculate. I've followed every tutorial I could find and I still keep getting a 0 for the delta time variable, which results in no animation... please can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here

```
export default class {
  constructor(options) {

  // Window Variables
  this.canvas;
  this.ctx;
  this.width;
  this.height;
  this.running = false;

  // Time Variables
  this.fps = 30;
  this.timePerTick = 1000/this.fps;
  this.delta = 0;
  this.now;
this.lastTime = Date.now();
this.timer = 0;
this.ticks = 0;

if(options != null) {

  if(options.width != null) 
    this.width = options.width;

  if(options.height != null)
    this.height = options.height;

  if(options.id != null) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "<canvas id='"+options.id+"' width='"+this.width+"' height='"+this.height+"'><canvas>";
  }
}

this.canvas = document.getElementById(options.id);
this.canvas.width = this.width;
this.canvas.height = this.height;

  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
}

init(callback) {

  callback();
  this.running = true;
}

update(callback) {

  if(this.running) {
    this.now = Date.now();
    this.delta = this.now - this.lastTime;
    this.timer += this.delta;
    this.lastTime = this.now;
  }

  if(this.timer >= this.timePerTick) {
    this.dt = this.timer/1000;
    callback();
    this.timer = 0;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(() => {this.update});
}
}
```

Comment: You are not executing this.update. Adding console.log() will show that

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(this.update)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell here, you're not calling `update` at each frame. Passing it an arrow function like you do would work if you needed to do more things than call `update`. But the current arrow function doesn't return the callback needed for `requestAnimationFrame`.

Just pass `update` to `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: No I'm actually calling it in my entry point file... this is a class file

Comment: requestAnimationFrame( ); takes the function it's going to run for the next frame.

Comment: i pressed enter by accident and when typing the edit it took too long

() => {this.update;} _does not_ execute update. In the entry point, you can call update but update doesn't call itself. Unless you've overridden requestAnimationFrame passing () => {this.update;} won't do anything.

Comment: No it actually does... this is just my way of wrapping it... this is how you can call a function with requestAnimationFrame and have a callback that is executed in another file... I actually figured out my delta time issue too though... thanks anyway